# Is there a way to update selected data with react query using setQueryData method?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I was reading on how it is possible to update existing query data with Query Client's `setQueryData` method.

Here is how I transform my data.

```
    {
      select: (data) => {
        let fullDaysArray = [] as Day[];
        data.docs.map((docSnapshot) => {
          const { id } = docSnapshot;
          let data = {
            ...docSnapshot.data(),
            documentId: id,
          } as Day;
          fullDaysArray.push(data);
        });
        fullDaysArray.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
        return fullDaysArray;
      },
```

I did it like this:

```
      queryClient.setQueryData("currentDiary", newData);
```

However I started getting these errors:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

And that is because, the `newData` that I am setting is not a firebase object that looks like this:
`Fu {_firestore: La, _userDataWriter: dh, _snapshot: qo, metadata: $u, query: Sa}`, but the actual already transformed object that looks like this:

```
[
        {
          dayName: "Monday",
          order: 1,
          uid: "1234",
          //...
```

Which obviously fails `data.docs.map((docSnapshot)`

Is there a way for me to only update the variable that I am returning from `select: (data)` method, which would be **fullDaysArray**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to only update the variable that I am returning from select: (data) method, which would be fullDaysArray?

No, there is not. The `data` that is returned from the `queryFn` is what gets put into the cache, and that is also what you have to write with `setQueryData`. `select` can exist on multiple observers, and it allows you to select and subscribe to different slices of the cached data.

It might be that `select` is not the best place in your situation to do the transformation - if you want to transform the data that gets stored in the query cache, you have to do it inside the queryFn.